# How can I get all objects from bucket from Google Cloud Storage by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-storage

I was managed to get an object by this gem -> https://github.com/moomerman/gstore

```
@client = GStore::Client.new(
    :access_key => 'myAK',
    :secret_key => 'mySK'
)
puts @client.get_object('bucket_name', 'test.xml')
```

Maybe, someone can help me to get all objects from bucket. Small example :) or a link will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ruby sample application on the Google Cloud Platform's GitHub organization:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-getting-started-ruby

Comment: Thank you very much :)
How can I implement it in my rails project?

Comment: Is there a way to do authentication without "Select an account" in a browser. Can I do auth in a code?

Comment: The Example application does not show proper pagination when more a bucket contains more than 1000 objects, as far as I can see. It's also generally appreciated to include a short snippet even in an answer with a link, because links have limited shelf life.

Answer (score 0):

If there are fewer than 1000 objects in a bucket, this will do:

```
bucket = storage.bucket "my-bucket"
files = bucket.files
files.each do |file|
  puts file.name
end
```

If it's more, you can either adjust the `max` parameter to `files` or, better, use a proper iteration:

```
files = bucket.files
files.all do |file|
  puts file.name
end
```